# how to validate id exists in array of array of ids of different collections in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I am having multiple forms as collection and needs to validate their ids in one request
for which i am taking from*name as name of forms and form id wrt to it. but i am not able to validate form_id wrt to formname provided. any idea to achive this would be very grateful.

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'doctor_id'       => 'required|exists:doctors,_id',
    'forms.*.name'    => ['required',Rule::in(['form1','form2','form3'])],
    'forms.*.user_id' => [ Rule::exists('users','_id')],
    'forms.*.form_id' => [ Rule::exists($request->forms.*.['name'],'_id')]
]);
```

Comment: i think you're better off using a closer validation aka custom code validation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures , that way you can group all the ids and do only query instead of a query per id.